# Javascript convert bigInt to string

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, bigint

I am trying to convert the following big int to a string in javascript with no success. My goal would end up with '582235852866076672'

```
var foo = 582235852866076672;
console.log(foo); // 582235852866076700

var baz = "'" + 582235852866076672 + "'";
console.log(baz); // '582235852866076700'

var emptyString = 582235852866076672+'';
console.log(emptyString); // 582235852866076700

var n = foo.toString();
console.log(n); // 582235852866076700
```

I figured the number was too big and was loosing precision as a result.
I included the [bigint library](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint) with no success:

```
var bigint = require('bigint');
var bigintLibrary = bigint(582235852866076672).toString();
console.log(bigintLibrary); //582235852866076700
```

The method toSting in the bigint library states:

> "Print out the bigint instance in the requested base as a string."

I appreciate all help and comments. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the number coming from?  The number you're talking about can't exist as a normal javascript number, so the source is important.

Comment: @AaronDufour the number is coming in the params of a post request, I have tried var jsonString = JSON.stringify(582235852866076672); with the same result console.log(jsonString); // 582235852866076700.

Comment: You're going to have to manually parse the params, then.  Unless you can have the client pass it as a string instead of a number?  The precision is lost as soon as the library parses it into a number, so by the time it gets to your code it's too late.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a precision issue--the number you're getting back (`582235852866076672`) is bigger than the max number representable in JavaScript, which is 2^53 or `9007199254740992`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do I get the integer 582235852866076672 into string format? Everything I try results in 582235852866076700

Comment: You put quotes around it, like I did. You can't represent a number bigger than the max size in JavaScript directly--it gets truncated (as you're seeing).

Comment: Thanks I am seeing that, I was more curious how to convert the integer 582235852866076672 to string the '582235852866076672', the data is coming in as an integer and I have to convert it to a string, I cannot just add quotes I have to convert it

Comment: So actually this seems to be a precision issue--as in, JavaScript is unable to represent that number precisely. The number is greater than 2^53, which is the max number representable in JavaScript.

Comment: It seems like I will have to manipulate the data into a string before it reaches the javascript side.

Comment: Yep. Sorry to have such a crappy answer, but that's what you're stuck with. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: To clarify, `2^53` is the maximum _integer_ representable in JavaScript.  The maximum _number_ representable in JavaScript is `2^1024`.

Comment: Not according to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5, which specifies that the Number type has exactly 2^53 values--which maps directly to IEEE 754 with an exception for NaN values (which all map to a single NaN value) and positive/negative Infinity. Unless I'm horribly misreading the spec.

Answer (score 13):

As of 2019, you can use the built-in BigInt and BigInt literal, first, do something like:

```
// Cast to BigInt:
var result = BigInt("1234567801234567890");
result = BigInt(1234567801234567890);

// Or use BigInt literal directly (with n suffix).
result = 1234567801234567890n
```

Then use built-in `toString` method:

```
console.log('my BigInt is', result.toString());
```

See [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `BigInt` methods `BigInt.prototype.toLocaleString()`, or `BigInt.prototype.toString()`. Hope that helps.

Click here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt for more `BigInt` info.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like even though there are three answers, only one of them kind of actually answers the question, but it's not the accepted answer...

---

**This is my answer:**

First of all, you don't need to import the BigInt library... BigInt is built-in to JavaScript (at least it is now), you can access it by calling the function: `BigInt(...)` or by adding an 'n' at the end of a number: `45625625443n`

BigInt can hold very big numbers, last I checked, the limit is 1 billion bits <sup>[1](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint/issues/174#issuecomment-437471065)</sup>. That means you could hold an integer around 1×10<sup>10<sup>9</sup></sup>, which in most cases you most likely won't need any integer that big.

As I showed above, you can build a BigInt by using the constructor (`BigInt(...)`) or by adding an 'n' to the end (`45625625443n`) <sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)</sup>

When using the constructor, the parameter can be any of the following (but as [jmrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6036428/jmrk) said in the comments, ***when putting in a number into the constructor, it will still lose precision***, so don't use a number):

```js
// String
   BigInt("1234567890987654321234567890")
   // -> 1234567890987654321234567890n

// Number
   BigInt(1234567890987654321234567890)
   // -> 1234567890987654297979715584n
   /* As said above, using a number in the constructor may lose precision,
      as seen here just input a string or use the n */

// BigInt
   BigInt(1234567890987654321234567890n)
   // -> 1234567890987654321234567890n

// Boolean
   BigInt(false) // 0n
   BigInt(true)  // 1n
```

You can't mix types in operations. You can't do any of the normal operations with normal JavaScript numbers, you must convert them into BigInts first.

```js
let big_int_number = BigInt(135445264365246564)

// Incorrect
big_int_number + 1365

// Correct (either one)
big_int_number + 1365n
big_int_number + BigInt(1365)
```

And finally to answer the real question: To turn a BigInt into a string, you just need to use the built-in methods <sup>[3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#instance_methods)</sup>:

```js
let big_int_number = BigInt("135445264365246564")
// or
let big_int_number = 135445264365246564n

// Using BigInt.prototype.toString()
let string_version = big_int_number.toString()


/* You probably don't need this method,
   but I just put it here just because */

// Using BigInt.prototype.toLocaleString()
let string_version = big_int_number.toLocaleString()
```

This works for both constructions ways...

```js
let n_constructed = 1234567890987654321234567890n
    n_constructed.toString()       // 1234567890987654321234567890n
    n_constructed.toLocaleString() // 1234567890987654321234567890n

let constructered = BigInt("1234567890987654321234567890")
    constructered.toString()       // 1234567890987654321234567890n
    constructered.toLocaleString() // 1234567890987654321234567890n
```

If you have any questions about BigInt, visit [MDN's reference page on `BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: Your examples are actually incorrect. `BigInt(1234567890987654321234567890)` gives `1234567890987654297979715584n`, and `BigInt(135445264365246564)` gives `135445264365246560n` (note `...60n` at the end). And that's working as intended, because the Number you're using as input can't hold that much precision. Using the `BigInt(123)` notation is generally not recommended because of this scalability issue; prefer `123n`.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! When I tested the examples I gave, I guess I didn't see that they did not work (or didn't see that the output wasn't the same as the input)... I will edit my answer to include what you said.